# How to make a CoroutineContext.Element not to propagate via launch/async in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, intellij-plugin

Is there a way to change how a custom `CoroutineContext.Element` is propagated through `launch` and `async` to satisfy the code below?

```
suspend fun CoroutingScope.foo(): Foo? = TODO()

fun test() = runBlocking {
  withContext(FooElement(foo1)) {
    assertSame(foo1, foo())
    coroutineScope {
      assertSame(foo1, foo())
    }
    launch {
      assertNull(foo())   
    }
    async {
      assertNull(foo())   
    }
  }
}
```

In my IntelliJ plugin, I'd like to marry `ProgressIndicator` with coroutines via a custom `progressScope` that injects a `ProgressElement(val pi: ProgressIndicator)` in `coroutineContext`, so if it's not a separate job created via `launch` or `async`, a nested `progressScope` uses `pushState`/`popState` against the parent `ProgressIndicator` instead of creating a new one.

So far, the only option I see is to replace `launch` and `async` with custom builders, but I'm not sure if I'll be able to enforce it in the codebase.